# Functions in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ but not in $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm struggling to come up with examples of functions which are in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ but not in $C(\mathbb{R}^2)$. I know that $H^1(\mathbb{R})\subset C(\mathbb{R})$, and I know the power law example of a function in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ that's not in $C(\mathbb{R}^3)$, but the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case eludes me.

Comment: Not really "research level", but a reasonable question... :)  Next time, maybe on MathStackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to focus on the unit ball $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$, $N\geq 2$. Consider the function
$$
u(x)=\sqrt{1-|x|}\cdot\left( \frac{1}{|\ln(1-|x|)|}\right)^\alpha
$$
with $1/2<\alpha<N/2$, which is singular at the origin.

PS. Note that the function is actually in $H^1_0(B)$.